# Daily server-side caching of 10,000 Google Maps geocoder responses

Tags: xml, json, google-maps, caching, geocoding

I'm currently looking into methods of implementing server-side caching of roughly 10,000 Google Maps geocoder responses in a J2EE web application. Since Google limits the number of geocoding requests to 15,000 per day, I need a method to store my requests for 24 hours. The requests originate from an XML file that sits on the server, and will eventually be updated daily.

Originally, I was thinking of just adding a little bit of extra information to the XML file where each address is stored (one timestamp in the file, and latitude/longitude values for each address). However, I'm wondering if it might not be considerably faster to store the cached data in a separate file, formatted as JSON. My concerns with this approach is:

- I'm much more familiar and comfortable working with XML than JSON
- I'm using jQuery for as much heavy lifting as possible, but I haven't seen much JSON-specific support in jQuery
- One example I've seen of getting JSON out of a file used `eval`, which I instinctively shy away from
- I just haven't found any good reference that has convinced me that JSON is worth the learning curve

What do you guys have to say? Will there be a noticable performance difference between using XML and JSON? If I'm better off doing this with JSON than XML, is there some really good documentation on best practices, or maybe a nice jQuery plugin I'm missing? Maybe there are other data formats I haven't considered beyond XML or JSON (though I already know I don't want to use a relational database).

I'd like it to be simple, intuitive, and fast. I know that the XML format is the first two, I'm not sure about the third.

Also, there's no reason that I have to use Google Maps' geocoding service. Any recommendations for other services that might work better for looking up a large number of requests, but doing so infrequently? I'm starting to look into some of the options [here](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-API/web/resources-non-google-geocoders)
but I'd love to get some input on particularly good/fast/easy-to-use services.

**Edit:** whatever service I use needs to support intersections as well as proper addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the files are small and local, there shouldn't be much difference between XML and JSON for storage, so you should go with what's easier for you.

[json.org](http://www.json.org/) has pointers to open source JSON parsers and serializers in just about any programming language imaginable, if you decide to go that route.

If `eval` in JavaScript is what scares you, JavaScript now has [`evalJSON`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/string/evalJSON) which ameliorates the code-exploit concerns.

Comment: In XML form, the pre-cached data is about 2 megabytes. Not too bad.

Comment: There's no reason to bother with evalJSON if the JSON file is something you generated and wrote to your own server.  Nothing wrong with eval in that circumstance.